# Current loop transmission using 3 - wires

Tags: current, 4-20ma

Is it possible to transmit 4-20mA signal using 3 wires without external power supply (using the loop power supply)?

Comment: Loop-powered 4-20mA sensors do exist. Only 2 wires necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You normally need only two wires to connect your device to the 4-20 mA loop.

Comment: Yes, but I am making a device to test IO devices. And my customer needs to be able to test 4-20mA input on the IO device with both two and three wires.

Comment: You are going to have to show a schematic of how you want to connect things.  In particular, what is the 3rd wire used for?